# How many magic workout secrets are there really?

Tags: muscle-gain

I'm still new to lifting but I've come across a lot of pages advertising for example Chris Hemsworth's workout program or Chris Evans etc.

I understand that they're likely not showing the real program they used but what I'm wondering is: whether there are secret combinations of exercises or if the super professional people are at the end of day also just using The GZCL and similar programs, obviously in combination with 'roids in many cases.

Comment: As long as there is one more person searching for the Ultimate Secret Workout Program there will be one more Ultimate Secret Workout Program.

Comment: If they were really secret, there'd be no way to count them.

Comment: I have the ultimate magic double secret workout in my pocket.  I'll sell it to you for $10,000.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are no secret workouts.

The beautiful demigod beefcakes known as Chris Hemsworth and Chris Evans (and for that matter, Chris Pratt) have personal trainers who tailor their every workout to their exact needs. No program. Just different workouts depending on the current short-term goals.

Need a bigger chest? We're adding this exercise to the plan.

Need bigger arms? We're adding that exercise to the plan.

Need to adjust the shoulder-to-bicep ratio? We're adding this exercise to the plan.

Need to do a photo shoot in three days? We're removing these items from your diet.

Need to shoot a topless combat scene next week? We're doing these workouts until then.

Again, they don't have a workout program. They have a group of trainers telling them what to do every single day based on a series of ever-changing short-term goals.

**The secret plans**

...are bullshit. There are no secret workouts. We know all the exercises. Unless you hire a trainer, you're on your own in the task of putting them together in a way that makes sense for your specific body, and your specific goals. And with some experience, you'll be able to do that for yourself by testing different things and seeing what works *for you*.

Anyone claiming they have a secret training program is trying to sell you something. Even worse, they're trying to sell you a bog-standard training program that you could have gotten for free by googling "how to [my goals] for people with [my body type]". There are gonna be some bad apples in those Google results too, but every now and then you'll find something that doesn't immediately ask for your credit card info and the deed to your house.

Comment: Also someone helping manage diet & nutrition to make the workouts more effective

Comment: "every single day", sixteen hours a day, for two months. ... Step one : be rich.

Comment: Plenty of very good athletes have a deep understanding of training methodology and organize it mostly on their own. They use trainers more as consultants and less as managers who tell them what to do.

Comment: Rob McElhenney gained and lost a ton of weight, and got very muscular, in a short amount of time for *It's always Sunny....* And he said it's [easy to do](https://www.menshealth.com/entertainment/a21285961/its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia-rob-mcelhenney-jacked-fit) just quit your job, get a full time trainer, personal chef, nutritionist and have professionals help you ever single day.

Comment: @BruceWayne he also winked and nodded at doing steroids https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPOzOanrNyg (3:15)

Comment: @llama ah, didn't know that but it figures. Further proves the point it's not just "hard work and secret XYZ"

Comment: Just looking at Chris Hemsworth's deltoid muscles, you can already tell he's also 'roiding.

Comment: "a photo shoot in three days" What can you change in three days? Do you mean weeks or even months?

Comment: @QuoraFeans you can get dehydrated in three days. (Used for aesthetic effect by bodybuilders and here allegedly movie stars, for manipulating weigh-in weight by boxers etc.)

Comment: Worth remembering -- they exercise and take care of their appearance like it's their full time job because it basically is their full time job (or at least a big component of it). And then almost every image you see of them will be (sometimes heavily) modified, starting with body makeup and ending with digital retouching (including video these days).

Answer (score 7):

### Start, and don't stop.

That is one magic secret that is so blatantly obvious, no-one really notices.

You won't improve if you don't begin something.  It doesn't have to be a highly focused program.

Some people are blessed, some are cursed, but every single person has to do work to improve.  Once you have formed that good habit of working on yourself, improvements will come.

You can suffer from choice overload, or "shopping paralysis" where there are too many options and the desire to choose the "best" option stops you from doing anything.

You generally can't go wrong with improvements to your core - that is a good foundation for hanging more specific work off later.  A weaker core makes more-targetted exercise less beneficial.

Of course rest days and light days are fine, as part of your habit.  A rest day is not an excuse to undo the previous work, its a "go for a walk" day instead of a gym day.

---

Stopping is to be avoided where possible.   Personal note - the two significant C19 lockdowns in my country lasted 6-8 weeks and that put me back.  Getting going again was difficult, if I'd maintained some level of "doing something" it wouldn't be such a challenge.

Comment: Works for marathons too.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 42 magic workout secrets, but if they're revealed, there'll be less and your count will be off!

That said, take a look at Wim Hof's work, which has at least been replicated by others, if hotly debated and dangerous
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wim_Hof

The essence is that systems responsible for preventing death in a healthy body can be both trained and carefully used to get more work out of the applicable systems (practically, the muscles, lungs, and temperature control loop) .. but at a cost of leading one closer to over-straining the body than is otherwise possible, potentially with dire consequences, such as blackout during activity, drowning, extreme frostbite, breakage of bone-muscle connections, excessive damage to muscles, etc.

However, this is not magic, and mostly adrenaline response

Comment: I joined this site just to compliment you on your use of the number 42.  Always remember your towel when you work out!

Comment: The link you provide seems to be strongly arguing that Wim Hof's methods do not work at all.